# Spring integration, auto wiring failed (null)

Tags: spring, spring-integration, autowired

I am using spring integration to listen to emails.

I have a Spring component named mailService that is instantiated and the method handledMail is called each time a new email arrives.

I wanted to add some more code into EmailService like this:

```
@Component(value="mailService")
public class EmailService {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
```

My issue is that I have a null pointer exception when accessing applicationContext

Do you have any idea where does this can come from? My applicationContext.xml file was read. All the channels have started and the emailService component has been instantiated by Spring. Should I add something specific in the configuration?

Some more code:

```
@Component(value="mailService")
public class EmailService {

    private final static Logger logger =  Logger.getLogger(EmailService.class);
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="mailSender")
    private JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender;


public EmailService() {
    initContext();
}

private void initContext() {
    RuleManager ruleManager = (RuleManager) applicationContext.getBean("localRuleManager");
    ContextEvidence evidence = new ContextEvidenceEntry(EvidenceType.ROLE, new String("Front Office"));
    ruleManager.addMultipleEvidence(evidence);
}
```

I have a null pointer exception in the first line of initContext, applicationContext being null

The listening channel is started as below;

```
final ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("receiveChannel", DirectChannel.class);
```

It was working fine before I added the applicationContext and the `initContext()` lines.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailService' defined in file [XXXX/EmailService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [XXXXEmailService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks

Gilles

Comment: I suggest you to add required=true in the @Autowired annotation, and paste the stack trace to have more clues about this issue

Comment: add some stacktrace of nullPointerException.

Comment: @Koitoer Required is the default.

Comment: Show the code where you're calling your service.

Comment: I have added the code to the post. Wondering if I shouldn't use postContruct instead

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't be using *any* of this. If you need the `RuleManager`, pass it as a constructor argument. Your code blocks conflict, but if you're trying to use the injected context from the constructor, then you're accessing the field before Spring has a chance to autowire it. Use constructor injection and it won't be a problem.